# WordPress: how can I get rss feed of just a single post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get an rss feed for a single post, meaning I just want the whole article in an rss format, exlcuding comments. Is there a way for me to do this in wordpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `/feed/rss/` on the end of a url give the excerpt of the post for example:

```
http://mediasafari.com/news/marketing-careers-announces-two-new-courses/feed/rss/
```

If you change your excerpt to show the full article then that should work:

```
<?php

function rssFullText($content) {
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rssFullText');

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case in 3.7; /feed/rss redirects to /feed/ which is doesn't contain the <content:encoded> tag...

Comment: Works4me, seems only /feed does the same job

Answer (score 15):

Appreciate this is an old one but incase anyone else stumbles upon this, append ?withoutcomments=1 to your URL:

```
http://mediasafari.com/news/marketing-careers-announces-two-new-courses/feed/rss/?withoutcomments=1
```

Comment: For some reason this does actually do exactly what you want and shows the entire post.  I was hesitant to try it at first because the name "withoutcomments" did not seem to fit what I was trying to do, but sure enough...

Comment: @Matt Shepherd , This works with some sites feed and doesn't on some :( I'm trying this on sites which provide full feed.